# up in UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST

Tags: ifconfig

There is a line in the output info of **sudo ifconfig**.

```
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

What kind of word type UP is? A verb?
It means enhance ,lift,raise?
Why write it as **UPPING BROADCAST** such as **RUNNING MULTICAST**?
Is RUNNING MULTICAST a phrase to modify BROADCAST?

dirkt is so kind to explain it in detail,the person who downgrade me would apologize for the action ,it is hard to fully understand many manual for a non-native english speaker.
It is not a joke to ask such kind of issue for a non-native english speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these are flags; it's not a complete sentence. *UP* is actually a preposition, not a verb (not that it matters), in contrast to *DOWN*, and an interface is said to be *up* if it's enabled to transmit and receive network packets. By default, `ifconfig` only lists network interfaces that are *up*. You need to use `ifconfig -a` to also see interfaces that are *down*. (Or use the more modern `ip` instead of `ipconfig` in the first place).

You can also change the state of the interface from *up* to *down*, or vice versa, using `ifconfig` (or `ip link`).

In the same way, *BROADCAST*, *MULTICAST* and *RUNNING* are other flags that describe characteristics of the network interface (able to do broadcasts, able to do multicasts, etc.)

Comment: dirkt is so kind to explain it in detail,the person who  downgrade me  would apologize for the action ,it is hard to fully understand many manual for a non-native english speaker.